# Exception: EOF in Header occuring while extracting zip from isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have generated a zip using streamwriter in isolated storage named **temp.zip** and return its bytes in stream for extraction. Please find the code as below

```
stream = LoadZipFromLocalFolder(filename);
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(stream))
    {
        ZipEntry entry;
        //EOF in header occuring on below line
        while ((entry = zipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(entry.Name);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.Name);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
                {
                    isoStore.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                }

                string fileFullPath = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
                Debug.WriteLine(fileFullPath);
                using (var streamWriter = new BinaryWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, isoStore)))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int size;
                    while ((size = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    }
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    streamWriter.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I created temp.zip, it has **ReadWrite**,**Share** permissions and also I tried to unzip manually, then its getting extracted properly without causing any error, but in code its showing error **EOF in HEADER**.

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: Is the original file generated by a Java library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the **EOF in header** by using just a simple code as follows :

```
Stream.Position =0;
```

Hope it helps to some one.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you used this line of code? Be more specific, it is not really helpful when you answer yourself this way and nobody knows what is the context.

Comment: I had the same error message "EOF In Header" using a MemoryStream to open an Excel 2007 document with NPOI.  Setting Position=0 on the MemoryStream before passing it to new XSSFWorkbook() resolved the issue.

Comment: I am using v1.2.0 of SharpZipLib on DOTNET Core 3.1.201 and this did not help

Comment: It doesn't make sense to set position to 0 while iterating the nextentry in zip.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer above by user `user2561128` and it did not solve the problem for me.

Instead I opted for installing the NuGet `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` v4.3.0 and with the following code it worked.

```cs
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipArchive, destinationFolder, overwriteFiles:true);
```

It also looks like somebody has found the same problem in a fork of npoi with this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/issues/246).